# Remove key points from edges of an object

Tags: python, opencv, sift, surf, keypoint

I am working with images with objects in it. I used canny edge detection and contours to detect and draw the edges of the objects in it. Then I used both SIFT and SURF to detect key points in the object. Here is the sample code I've been working on.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread(image)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv.Canny(gray, 100,200)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(edges, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
outimg = cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
sift = cv.xfeatures2d_SIFT.create()
kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(outimg,None)
```

Is there any way to remove the key points that are on the edge? Answer with example will be really helpful. 
Thanks.

[image: Original Image]
[image: output image]

Comment: You can add the image here for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: I have added the images ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pointPolygonTest](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest) method to filter detected keypoints. Use detected contours as boundary polygon. You will also be able to define desired margin.

Simaple example (fot 4 point contour):

```
def inside_point(self, point, rect):

        # point is a list (x, y)
        # rect is a contour with shape [4, 2]

        rect = rect.reshape([4, 1, 2]).astype(np.int64)

        dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(rect,(point[0], point[1]),True)

        if dist>=0:
            # print(dist)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

You can also draw contours on mask image and to check if the point is inside contours, just check the pixel value with the point coordinates, and if it not 0 then point is valid.

Seems everythig woeks fine:
I have no xfeatures2d, so used ORB features here.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('image.jpg')
#img = cv.resize(img,(512,512))
img = cv.copyMakeBorder(img,20,20,20,20, 0)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_ , gray = cv.threshold(gray,20,255,cv.THRESH_TOZERO)

gray=cv.erode(gray,np.ones( (5,5), np.int8) )
edges = cv.Canny(gray, 100,200)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(edges, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

orb = cv.ORB_create(nfeatures=10000)
kp, des = orb.detectAndCompute(gray,None)

outimg = cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

k = []
for cont in contours:   
    for i in kp: 
        (x, y) =i.pt
        dist = cv.pointPolygonTest(cont, (x,y), True)
        if dist>=0:
            k.append(i)

for i in k:
    pt=(int(i.pt[0]),int(i.pt[1]) )
    cv.circle(outimg,pt,3, (255,255,255),-1)

cv.imwrite('result.jpg',outimg)        
cv.imshow('outimg',outimg)
cv.waitKey()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. An example will be even more helpful.

Comment: Updated, also check alternative solution at the end.

Comment: I am still finding it difficult to remove keypoints using the function.  I tried to append the keypoints  in a new list if it's not in the contour but shows error when I use cv2.drawKeypoints function because the new list is not of type keypoint. 
Would you mind explaining your solution thoroughly?

Comment: Can you provide the code to reproduce your current issue. And check your contours.

Comment: I added the code in a comment below ... please take a look ...

Comment: It worked ... Thanks very much for your continuous help!

Answer (score 1):

I am still finding it difficult to remove key points from the given image.   I tried to append the key points in a new list if it's not in the contour but shows an error when I use cv2.drawKeypoints function because the new list is not of type keypoint. This is the work I have done so far.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread(image)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv.Canny(gray, 100,200)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(edges, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
outimg = cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
sift = cv.xfeatures2d_SIFT.create()
kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(outimg,None)
k = cv.KeyPoint()
for i in kp: 

    (x, y) =i.pt
    dist = cv.pointPolygonTest(contours[0], (x,y), True)
    if dist>=0:
        k1.append(k)
```